# cant access properties file value in tiles spring mvc

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I want to use values inside properties file directly inside my jsp. I am using tiles and tried following things to make it work.

```
<!-- Load guide properties file -->

    <bean id="GuideProperties"
        class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertiesFactoryBean">
        <property name="locations">
            <list>
                <value>WEB-INF/text/guide.properties</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean
        class="org.springframework.web.context.support.ServletContextAttributeExporter">
        <property name="attributes">
            <map>
                <entry key="GuidedTut" value-ref="GuideProperties" />
            </map>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

and i tried to access in jsp as follow

```
${GuidedTut.guide.welcome.firstline}
```

project runs well but i cant see properties file value in jsp.

Comment: check whether  http://thinkinginsoftware.blogspot.in/2012/01/access-properties-file-from-jspjstl-el.html will help you

Answer (score 0):

You can get the property values in jsp by propertyplaceholder and using spring tag in jsp:
In your dispatcher context xml:

```
    <!-- PropertyPlaceHolder -->
    <util:properties id="propertyConfigurer" location="WEB-INF/test/guide.properties"/>
    <context:property-placeholder properties-ref="propertyConfigurer"/>
```

In your jsp:

```
    <%@ taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" %>
    ...
    <spring:eval expression="@propertyConfigurer.getProperty('GuidedTut.guide.welcome.firstline')" />
```